# Adding a Service Reference to a NetTcp service using Add Service Reference... dialog

Tags: c#, wcf

I defined a service. It´s service model node in the App.config is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBindingConfiguration">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="Products.ProductsServiceImpl">
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8080/Whatever" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingConfiguration" name="NetTcpBinding_IProductsService"
                contract="Products.IProductsService" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

But when trying to add the service reference to a client app, I run the service, then I try to add the service reference using the Add Service Reference... dialog, but I can´t locate the service.

[image]

If I add an endpoint that uses basicHttpBinding, then the service is localizable via the Add Service Reference dialog.

I tried adding an endpoint that uses mexTcpBinding, but I got an error when trying to start the service, I got an error saying that the contract IMetadataExchange could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by my service.

What could I be missing?

**Update:**

This service is being opened using the ServiceHost class (an extract of the WPF App that's in charge of starting the service:):

```
var productsServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProductsServiceImpl));
productsServiceHost.Open();
stop.IsEnabled = true;
start.IsEnabled = false;
status.Text = "Service Running";
```

And I used a WCF Library to create the service (where the service and contract are defined))

Comment: Did you try exposing the mextcpbinding for metadata exchange for the end point.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie, how do I do that?, please...

Comment: I already mentioned that I did what's suggested in the WCF NetTcp... post with no success. I added the behavior, added the new endpoint with the "mex" address, but when running and trying to start the service I get an error saying that the contract name IMetadataExchange could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service. I notice that the behavior has a name "metadataSupport", but it is never used. I don't know where to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I used this blog: http://debugmode.net/2010/06/16/nettcpwcfserviceinwindowservice/

1. The "mex" endpoint should use "mexTcpBinding"
2. Have to define the host base address, and leave the main endpoint address blank
3. httpGetEnabled was set to false

Here's the complete service model node (App.config)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBindingConfiguration">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="Products.ProductsServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="metadataSupport">
            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingConfiguration" name="NetTcpBinding_IProductsService" 
                contract="Products.IProductsService" />
            <endpoint name="MetaDataTcpEndpoint"
                      address="mex"
                      binding="mexTcpBinding"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8080/Whatever" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="metadataSupport">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When placing the address in the Add Service Reference... dialog, it should be as:

```
net.tcp://localhost:8080/Whatever/mex
```

Although if you have started your service, when pressing Go in the Add Service Reference..., it appends the mex text for you if you haven't

Security mode="none" is usefull to access the service from other machines of the network

Happy coding.